# Error when seek to in VideoView Android from a url

Tags: android, video, media-player

When I start playing the video I didn't have any problem, but when I seek to a position that is not buffered, the video playing stops and show me a dialog with an error.

The logcat trace is this:

```
07-31 10:51:23.163      189-846/? D/audio_hw_primary﹕ out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
07-31 10:51:23.188    189-29871/? E/﹕ not in avi mode
07-31 10:51:23.191    189-29871/? E/﹕ not in avi mode
07-31 10:51:23.207  22651-22668/? W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (3, 0)
07-31 10:51:23.901      746-819/? I/art﹕ Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 70558(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 3(48KB) LOS objects, 24% free, 48MB/64MB, paused 2.201ms total 146.600ms
07-31 10:51:24.354    189-13848/? D/NuPlayerDriver﹕ seekTo(0xb1ffd340) 1325959 ms
07-31 10:51:24.442    189-29844/? I/NuCachedSource2﹕ new range: offset= 136309244
07-31 10:51:24.952      189-846/? I/AudioFlinger﹕ BUFFER TIMEOUT: remove(4097) from active list on thread 0xb5a06000
07-31 10:51:25.005    189-29832/? E/MPEG4Extractor﹕ Video is malformed
07-31 10:51:25.161    189-29846/? I/NuPlayerDecoder﹕ [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] resubmitting CSD
07-31 10:51:25.161    189-29848/? I/NuPlayerDecoder﹕ [OMX.google.aac.decoder] resubmitting CSD
07-31 10:51:25.161    189-29831/? I/NuPlayer﹕ buffer low, pausing...
07-31 10:51:25.162    189-29851/? I/SoftAAC2﹕ Initially configuring decoder: 44100 Hz, 2 channels
07-31 10:51:25.163    189-29846/? I/NuPlayerDecoder﹕ [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] resubmitting CSD
07-31 10:51:25.165    189-29871/? E/﹕ not in avi mode
07-31 10:51:25.166    189-29832/? E/MPEG4Extractor﹕ Video is malformed
07-31 10:51:25.166    189-29851/? W/SoftAAC2﹕ aacDecoder_DecodeFrame decoderErr = 0x4002
07-31 10:51:25.166    189-29851/? W/SoftAAC2﹕ AAC decoder returned error 0x4002, substituting silence
07-31 10:51:25.168  22651-22668/? W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (703, 0)
07-31 10:51:25.168    189-29846/? E/NuPlayerDecoder﹕ Stream error for OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc (err=-1007), EOS successfully queued
07-31 10:51:25.168    189-29871/? E/﹕ not in avi mode
07-31 10:51:25.169    189-29831/? E/NuPlayer﹕ received error(0xfffffc11) from video decoder, flushing(0), now shutting down
07-31 10:51:25.171  22651-22668/? W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (701, 0)
07-31 10:51:25.171  22651-22668/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -1007)
07-31 10:51:25.171  22651-22651/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-1007)
07-31 10:51:25.171  22651-22651/? D/VideoView﹕ Error: 1,-1007
```

The video url is this: 
http://nws.nice264.com/vod/pcat/android_800k_228p/9f8058833cf4532cf262.mp4

And my code is this:

```
        VideoView video;
        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
        video.setVideoURI(vidUri);
        video.start();
        MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
        vidControl.setAnchorView(video);
        video.setMediaController(vidControl);
```

Can anyone says me what's wrong here.

Comment: I don't think this will fix your problem but it will be good to start video in prepared listner like this
 VideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                VideoView.start();
            }
        });

Comment: No this don't fix my problem

Comment: https://github.com/StickmanVentures/immersive-videoplayer-android,,,,try this link sir...it works according to your demand

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working code and i can seek to any position without any error. May be it could help you.

```
public void playvideo(final String videopath, final VideoView v,
        final ProgressBar progressBar) {
    Log.e("path is", "" + videopath);
    try {

        Uri video = Uri.parse(videopath);

        v.setVideoURI(video);

        v.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp,
                            int width, int height) {
                        mediaController = new MediaController(MugshotVideoPlayer.this);
                        v.setMediaController(mediaController);
                        mediaController.setAnchorView(v);
                    }
                });
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                v.start();
            }

        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        System.out.println("Video Play Error :" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

And here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:gravity="center">
<VideoView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/videoIntruder"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="320dp" >
</VideoView>

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try to use the url of the question? I don't think your code works with that url

Answer (score 0):

I see `Video is malformed` in your log. It means your **Video** on your server is bad-formatted and broken.